# Access bound data from clicked List Item in UI5 controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to fetch data from an input list item (bound to a JSON model) in UI5 (XML views & JS controller).

[image: Shape of the list, fetch data from the square brackets and quantity input field]

```xml
<List id="orderList" headerText="Menu Items: " items="{/Items}">
  <InputListltem label="{i_Category}, ({i_Points}), [{i_Category_IDA}]">
    <!-- ... -->
  </InputListltem>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the reference of the InputListItem (e.g. in its `press`-handler) or any of its child control that still has the same binding context as the one from the InputListItem.
2. Call [`getBindingContext(modelName?)`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#methods/getBindingContext) on it with the corresponding model name as an argument to get the binding context.
3. From that context, call [`getObject()`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.Context#methods/getObject) or [`getProperty(propertyName)`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.Context#methods/getProperty) to get the bound model data of that list item. For example:

   ```xml
   <InputListItem xmlns="sap.m" press=".onItemPress" label="...">
   ```

   ```js
   { // Controller
     onItemPress: function(event) {
       const boundContext = event.getSource().getBindingContext(/*modelName?*/);
       const data = boundContext.getObject(); /* returns: {
         i_Category: "Proteins",
         i_Points: 10,
         i_Category_ID: "PRT" 
       } */
       // Retrieve specific property value:
       const category = boundContext.getProperty("i_Category"); // returns "Proteins"
     },
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Getting the current context for the list
var myContexts = this.byId("createOrder--orderList").getBinding("items").getCurrentContexts();
// Get object binded to the context
var myBoundDataObjects = myContexts.map(function(context) {
  return context.getObject();
});
// Looping on the bounded data to change the values of the JSON Array
for (var i = 0; i < myBoundDataObjects.length; i++) {
  if (myBoundDataObjects[i].i_Category_ID === categoryID) {
    myBoundDataObjects[i].i_Quantity = parseInt(Qty, 10);
    break;
  }
}
// Setting the json model in order to pass it to different methods/classes
var ordersModel = new JSONModel(myBoundDataObjects);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(ordersModel , "ordersModel");
```